# Direction of undetermined contact force & undetermined Normal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, contact-mechanics

I am not getting the following sattements related to contact force and normal force which are:

1. If the direction of contact force cannot be determined, it should be shown as two components.
2. If perpendicular to the surface of contact cannot be drawn, the normal force will act perpendicular to the surface of the body.
3. If neither can be done, normal force has to be drawn as two components- one in the X- direction and one in the Y-direction. The forces acting along the X and Y directions are independent of each other.

What does these following satements are trying to explain?

Comment: Where did you get these statements from? A book? A website? A video? Please provide the source link or name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In a situation where two corners are in contact, the contact force (acting on the blue part below) can be in any direction (and magnitude) and thus can be decomposed into two components.

   [image: fig1]
2. In a situation where a corner is in contact with an edge, then the direction of the normal force is defined as being perpendicular to the edge

   [image: fig2]
3. What is missing from the above (since statement #3 is the same as statement number #1 in the question) is the situation where two edges are in contact.

   In this case, the direction of the contact force is again perpendicular to the surfaces, but there are *two* contact locations with two independent forces, at the ends of the contact, Alternatively, you can have a contact force plus and contact moment applied to the body.

   [image: fig3]

As a general rule, when two bodies are in contact, think of the ways they can slide past each other, and the contact forces act in a way perpendicular to the allowed motion. By definition, contact forces do not add or remove work from a system, and thus must act perpendicular to relative motion (since force in direction of motion defines work).

---

For example, if a curved part is in contact with a point, then the direction of the contact force is defined by the circular part and it goes through the center (as it is perpendicular to the surface of the circle).

[image: fig4]

Another common case, and a combination of #2 and #3 above is when a circle is tangent to an edge. Then according to #3 there should be two contact points at the ends of the contact, but because the contacting area is just a point, there still exists only one contact force.

[image: fig5]

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me.